# js replaceChild preserve click listener or inline onclick method

Tags: javascript, html, templates, dom, onclick

I have a div that's used to display a work area for the user, and content is loaded dynamically. When trying to implement a previous/back button, my content loads, but if that content contains an onclick listener it doesn't trigger.

My work area is an empty `<div id="work-area"></div>`

I'm using `cloneNode()` and `replaceChild()` like so:

```
const workArea = document.getElementById(`work-area`)
let backup = workArea.cloneNode(true)

closeWorkArea = () => {
    workArea.innerHTML = ``
    backup = workArea.cloneNode(true)
    workArea.parentNode.replaceChild(backup, workArea)
}
previous = () => {
    workArea.parentNode.replaceChild(backup, workArea)
}
```

and when I load a certain page, I create a backup and load a template:

```
openItem = (index) => {
    backup = workArea.cloneNode(true)
    workArea.innerHTML = ``
    ...
    const itemPageCard = document.getElementById(`item-page-card`).content.cloneNode(true)
    // NOTE : I've tried both of these assignments below, neither work
    itemPageCard.children[2].addEventListener(`click`, () => { promptDelete(index) })
    itemPageCard.children[2].setAttribute(`onclick`, `promptDelete(${index})`)
    ...
    workArea.appendChild(itemPageCard)
}
```

The `promptDelete()` function loads a template which contains a button that will delete the users data, as well as a button that calls `previous()`

```
promptDelete = (index) => {
    backup = workArea.cloneNode(true)
    workArea.innerHTML = ``
    const prompt = document.getElementById(`prompt-delete`).content.cloneNode(true)
    ...
    // NOTE : Clicking this does work, and loads the previous page data
    prompt.children[2].children[0].addEventListener(`click`, () => { previous() })
    prompt.children[2].children[1].addEventListener(`click`, () => { deleteItemByIndex(index) })
    workArea.appendChild(prompt)
}
```

Once the previous page is loaded, the click events from the initial `openItem()` call no longer occur. I suspect its the `workArea.parentNode.replaceChild(backup, workArea)`, but don't know how to restore those listeners. Even if I use the inline method `setAttribute('onclick', ..)` I can see the `onclick="promptDelete(0)"` inside the html, confirming it's cloning correctly, however still nothing

**Note** : I can't just use `openItem()` with an index in lieu of `previous()` because I also load other types of content into the work area

Comment: Can you create a stack snippet in which we can run your code? That would help a lot with seeing the issue actually happening.

Comment: I will have to do that in a bit. I'm heading to bed rn